# PHP "Trying to get property of non-object" When trying to get Bungie.net ID

Tags: php, json, api, xampp

I've been following [this tutorial](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~walkermi/HowToIntro.html) on [how to find my membership id](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~walkermi/HowTo3.html).

This part is what I'm stuck on. I have a simple PHP file using that code with the API key and correct settings. Its giving me property of non object error. Here:

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'REMOVED FOR SECURITY';
$ch = curl_init();
‘https://www.bungie.net/platform/destiny/1/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/GAMERTAG REMOVED FOR SECURITY');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));

$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
echo $json->Response;
?>
```

The link inside the code would usually have a gamertag, like 'MajorNelson' or something like that. It gives some error when you go to it,  but that link doesnt matter. When hosting the php file using XAMPP I get this error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in `E:\xampp\htdocs\bungieapi.php` on line 9

Line 9 is the echo line before the `?>`.

Comment: `var_dump($json)` to see what's inside it.

Comment: `curl_exec()` returns `false` when there is an error. You are just assuming that everything works, and then you are confused when it doesn't work. You should always check for errors, when things can go wrong (which they always can when dealing with other servers).

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors:

```
// ...
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if ($json === false) {
    die('ERROR: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (isset($obj->Response)) {
    echo $obj->Response;
} else {
    echo 'ERROR: The "Response" property is not there';
}
```

Comment: I add that after the echo and it just says "ERROR:" under the property error. Do I have to have anything specific installed?

Comment: You should download [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) then and try to get it working there.

Comment: @Alright so heres what I got, I think this led to earlier errors. On the last line I get "Missing semicolon, Expected an identifier and instead saw >. Missing ";" before statement"